# content flows when the bootstrap alert message appear

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am across a little bit confusing problem. I want to display an alert message on the top of the screen when the account is activated. but problem is that when messages shows, the welcome blue box moves down which I don't want. When I close the alert message the content comes in their real position.

[image: this is the picture without alert message]

[image: this is the image after alert message overflow content]

This is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php include_once('head.php'); ?>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
</head>
<body>

        
        <?php 
            if(isset($_SESSION['act'])) ?>
            <div class="text-center alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <?php echo $_SESSION['act']; ?>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">
                    &times;
                 </button>
            </div> <?php
        ?>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="message-container">
                <div class="message-inner-box">
                    <div class="title-container clearfix">
                        <p class="heading"> Welcome back, </p>
                        <p class="subheading"> Log In!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="image-header">
                <img src="../image/sign up.png" alt="file not found" class="signUp-image">
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="signuUp-header">
                    <div class="signUp-inner">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-header">
                                <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Enter Email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-header">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="password" id="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Password" />
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-lock" id="passwordSeen"> </i></span>    
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-header">
                                <div class="forgetPassword text-right"> 
                                    <a href="forgetpassword.php">forget Password </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-header rememberMe">    
                                <input type="checkbox" class="" />
                                <label class="form-check-label"> Remember me </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-header">
                                <input type="submit" class="signUpButton" name="submit"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>

                        <div class="signUpFooter text-center">
                            <span> I'm a new member <a href="signup.php"> Sign Up</a></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>

        </div>
    </div> 

<script src="../javascript/app.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the css code

```
/*Message box*/
.message-inner-box{
    height: 300px;
    width:  300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: -3.2em;
    margin-left: -5em;
    background-color: var(--message-box-color);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.title-container {
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: var(--message-color);
}
.title-container p {
    margin: 0;
}
.heading {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.subheading {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 800;
} 


/*Sign Up page*/

.signUp-image {
    height: 60%;
    width:  60%;
}
.signuUp-header {
    padding-top: 5rem;
}
.form-header {
    margin-bottom: 2.5em;
}
.input-field {
    height: 3em;
    width: 80%;
    padding: .3rem 2rem;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: 1px solid var(--input-field-color);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: do you mean the rest of content drops/moves down? I not seeing float'ing in your picture. If so use absolute positioning on the alert

Comment: if you see second pictuer carefully then you will find that welcome blue box moves down

Comment: Ok, Ive updated to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

You can add the style property to the alert div to include a negative bottom margin that repositions the element under this alert box.

```
<div style="margin-bottom: -50px" class="text-center alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
```

Comment: it overflow the image

Comment: What do you mean by overflow? Does the blue circle still move down to make room? Or does other behavior occur?

Comment: as you can in second picture that blue circle flows down due to when alert message appear. it want that blue circle should at this real position when the message appear. but when i use fixed or sticky it flows the image

Comment: Have you tried moving the entire div containing the alert inside the container-fluid div?

Comment: yes but the problem is that container fluid container padding property but i want alert message at the full width of the screen

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer based on what you suggested. You can also use the z-index property if you want the alert to appear over or under the circle.